# Error about string rotate Quiz: std::out_of_range: basic_string

Tags: c++

I'm a fresher here.

I write a class for a small Quiz called string rotate: given a string and its length and a specific position, return a rotated sting. e.g "ABCDEFGH",8,4
return："FGHABCDE"

the class has passed the online detection, but works incorrect in my computer when I run the test cpp file, and the error shows:

`libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type       std::out_of_range: basic_string
(lldb)`

Here is the class:

```
#ifndef basic_string_rotate_hpp
#define basic_string_rotate_hpp

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class StringRotation {
public:
    string rotateString(string A, int n, int p) {
        string B,C;
        B = A.substr(p+1,n-(p+1)); // back value
        C = A.substr(0,p+1); // front value
        A = B + C;               // write code here
        return A;
    }
};
#endif /* basic_string_rotate_hpp */
```

Here is the cpp file which I use this to test previous class:

```
#include "basic_string_rotate.hpp"
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
using std::cin; using std::cout; using std::endl; using      std::string;using std::vector;
int main()
{
    string A = "cao ni ma bi", new_A; // initialize must use " ",   rather than this ' '
    int p = 3;
    auto n = (int)(A.size());
    StringRotation string;
    cout << string.rotateString(A,p,n);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It looks like you have the parameters backwards.  You call it as `string.rotateString(A,p,n);` but you define it as `rotateString(string A, int n, int p)`.  should `n` in the function be the size or the rotation position?

Comment: What is this `string A = "cao ni ma bi", new_A`? Remove the `, new_A`

Comment: Why do you pass the size explicitly when you get it with the std::string object implicitly? (Even with a good old c-string, you could still apply strlen...)

Comment: actually you are right.. I m so stupid...it should be string.rotateString(A,n,p), not string.rotateString(A,p,n)